# Add event to list of element when into viewport

Tags: jquery, css, events, scroll

I've got a lot elements on the page, I use the function to check is the element on viewport or not, if so add some class with animation. But how to add event to certaine element but not to all. [codpen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/JbQObp?editors=0110)

```js
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
      var $elem = $(elem);

      // Get the scroll position of the page.
      var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
      var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
      var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

      // Get the position of the element on the page.
      var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
      var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

      return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
  }

function checkAnimation() {
        var $newsArrowRight = $('.box .arrow');
//         for (var i = 0; i < $newsArrowRight.length; i++) {
//           // if ($newsArrowRight.hasClass('fade-in-right-js')) return;
//           if(isElementInViewport($newsArrowRight[i])){
//             console.log($newsArrowRight[i]);
//             $newsArrowRight[i].addClass('fade-in-right-js');
//           }

//         }
        // $.map( $newsArrowRight, function(e) {
        //   if (e.hasClass('fade-in-right-js')) return;
        //   if(isElementInViewport(e)){
        //     e.addClass('fade-in-right-js');
        //   }
        // });
        if ($newsArrowRight.hasClass('fade-in-right-js')) return;
        //
        if(isElementInViewport($newsArrowRight)){
          $newsArrowRight.addClass('fade-in-right-js');
        }
        
    }

    // Capture scroll events
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        checkAnimation();
    });
```

```css
.box {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 20vh;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.box .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  transform: translateX(-90px);
}
.box .arrow.fade-in-right-js {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: fade-in-right 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: fade-in-right 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: fade-in-right 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: fade-in-right 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: fade-in-right 1s ease-in-out;
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">text</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">text</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">text</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">text</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">arrow</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">arrow</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">arrow</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">arrow</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa!
  <div class="arrow">arrow</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is ues $each [codpen](http://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/JbQObp?editors=0010)

```
   function checkAnimation() {
    var $newsArrowRight = $.find('.box .arrow');
    $.each($newsArrowRight, function() {
      var element = $(this);
      if (element.hasClass('fade-in-right-js')) return;

      if(isElementInViewport(element)){
      element.addClass('fade-in-right-js');
    }
    });
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function() {
    checkAnimation();
});
```